# Selenium webdriver- Unable to click on submenu - amazon.in

Tags: selenium-webdriver, click, submenu

I am trying to click on a submneu in amazon.in
I could expand the main menu. but can't click on sub menu. I tried two methods. But its showing errors.

Mail category html  code:

```
<li class="nav_pop_li nav_cat nav_divider_before" id="nav_cat_2">Books</li>
```

Subcategory html

```
<a href="/Books/b/ref=nav_shopall_books_all?ie=UTF8&amp;node=976389031" class="nav_a nav_item">All Books</a>
```

I used the following methods

Method 1

```
driver.get("http://amazon.in");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
            WebElement moveonmenu = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@id='nav_cat_2']"));
            actions.moveToElement(moveonmenu).moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='nav_a nav_item']"))).click().perform();
```

Method 2

```
driver.get("http://amazon.in");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    //locate the menu to hover over using its xpath
            WebElement menu = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@id='nav_cat_2']"));

            //Initiate mouse action using Actions class
            Actions builder = new Actions(driver);    

            // move the mouse to the earlier identified menu option
            builder.moveToElement(menu).build().perform();

            // wait for max of 5 seconds before proceeding. This allows sub menu appears properly before trying to click on it
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5); 
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//a[@class='nav_a nav_item']")));  // until this submenu is found

            //identify menu option from the resulting menu display and click
            WebElement menuOption = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='nav_a nav_item']"));
            menuOption.click();
```

Please tell me why its not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **"Method 1"**, there was **issue with hovering**, I guess. Must I say, it was just clicking on the "Main Category" element".

In **Method 2"**, the hovering of "Main Category" is properly happening. The **only problem was with the xpath you have chosen to click on the "Sub-Category"**. The xpath is actually associated with multiple elements. Hence, the code was failing.

Just replace the following codes in your **Method 2**, it will work:-

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//a[@class='nav_a nav_item' and .=\"All Books\"]")));
```

and

```
WebElement menuOption = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='nav_a nav_item' and .=\"All Books\"]"));
```

**Note:-** In the above, I have used **All Books** as the text to be clicked. 
**(** This text must exactly match with what is being displayed in the webpage.**)**
Similarly, you can replace **All Books** with other texts such as "Bestsellers, New Releases & Pre-orders, etc."